# Como imprimir uma string de um vetor de strings em C?

Tags: c, array, string

Tenho um **vetor de strings(`palavras[x][y]`)**, consigo ler cada palavra que será um elemento do vetor, mas não consigo imprimir qualquer destas palavras armazenadas.

`printf("%s",palavras[a][b]),` não funciona.

**Aqui estão minhas tentativas:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char nomes[1][15];
int i;
scanf("%s",&nomes[0][15]);
scanf("%s",&nomes[1][15]);
printf("%s",&nomes[0][15]);
// for(i=0;i<=15;i++){
// printf("%c",nomes[0][i]);
// }
system("PAUSE");    
return 0;
}
```

O `for` comentado também não deu certo.Como posso proceder?

Comment: Você quer um vetor com apenas uma *string*, ou seja ele só terá um elemento com uma *string* de até 14 caracteres? Se for mais de um, é sempre 2? Precisa usar um laço por algum motivo ou pode ser do jeito mais simples?

Comment: ele conta do 0 então seriam 2 strings e 16 caracteres, palavras[0][15] = 'seu' ; palavras[1][15]='comentario'. Eu gostaria do jeito mais simples de se escrever qualquer um desses vetores na tela.

Comment: preciso de um método pra um vetor de n strings.

Comment: preciso imprimir alguma dessas strings.

Comment: Existe algum motivo para estar a tentar imprimir os caracteres das strings um a um usando o `%c`, em vez de imprimir a string toda com `%s` ?

Comment: eu deixei a string fixa, e os caracteres da string iriam variar até terminar a string, no laço for. Mas também não deu certo.

Comment: mas o que eu quero é imprimir a string toda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problemas

Comecemos pela analise dos problemas que tem no código.

- Se estava a tentar criar um vetor de 2 `strings`, como indicou no comentário, então o tamanho não saiu certo, pois foi declarado como `char nomes[1][15];` e por isso ficou com tamanho `1` em vez de `2`.
- Tanto os `scanf`s como os `printf`s não estão certos. Analisemos o primeiro `scanf`:

  ```
  scanf("%s", &nomes[0][15]); //leitura incorreta
  ```

  Está a tentar ler uma `string` (`%s`) mas depois passa o endereço do 16º 
  caratere da primeira `string`, e por isso não está correto.

  Em vez disso devia fazer apenas assim:

  ```
  scanf("%s", nomes[0]); //ler um texto para a primeira posição do array de strings
  ```
- No `for` estava também a tentar imprimir letra a letra mas isso é bem mais complicado que imprimir a `string` toda com `%s`, assim como também seria necessário parar se encontrasse o terminador `\0`.

### Solução

Acertando os detalhes mencionados anteriormente o seu código ficaria assim:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char nomes[2][15]; //agora com tamanho para 2 strings

    scanf("%s", nomes[0]);
    scanf("%s", nomes[1]); 
    printf("%s" ,nomes[0]);

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        printf("%s ",nomes[i]); //agora com %s
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/FHlnUA)

Comment: @GustavoViana o que vem dentro de `[` `]` indica o tamanho, logo quantos permite. Se tem `nomes[1][...]` então só tem tamanho `1`. `nomes[2][15]` significa tamanho 2, ou seja 2 `strings` e 15 carateres cada uma sendo que tem que ter espaço para o `\0` logo só terá 14 careteres uteis para cada `string`

Comment: então vi isso agora numa apostila, ele conta do 0 mas pra vetor[2], vai existir, vetor[0], vetor[1](2 vetores). eu acreditava mesmo que ele contava até o 2. Obrigado pela ajuda. Entendi, os caracteres seriam 14 + \0, para vetor[15].

Comment: @GustavoViana Exatamente, `vetor[2]` vai fazer com que tenha 2 elementos(strings) o `0` e o `1`